# jQuery absolute sidebr scrolling, stop at the top of parent and at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi guys so i have this code ive done which when scrolling the sidebar moves up from bottom to top but im stuck with how to stop the scrolling once the sidebar hits the top of the main conatiner - can someone maybe help me with this?

code is:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.parallax-sidebar').css('bottom', '+' + ((scrolledY * 1.3)) + 'px');
});
```

I have a fiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/06qwtgt6/1/

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    /********************************************************************************/
    /* Parallax Scrolling */

    // Cache the Window object
    var $window = $(window);

    $('[data-type]').each(function () {
        $(this).data('offsetY', parseInt($(this).attr('data-offsetY')));
        $(this).data('Xposition', $(this).attr('data-Xposition'));
        $(this).data('speed', $(this).attr('data-speed'));
    });

    // For each element that has a data-type attribute
    $('div[data-type="background"]').each(function () {

        var $self = $(this),
            offsetCoords = $self.offset(),
            topOffset = offsetCoords.top;

        $(window).bind('scroll', function () {

            if (($window.scrollTop() + $window.height()) > (topOffset) &&
                 ((topOffset + $self.height()) > $window.scrollTop())) {

                var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $self.data('speed'));

                if ($self.data('offsetY')) {
                    yPos += $self.data('offsetY');
                }

                var coords = '50% ' + yPos + 'px';

                $self.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

            };

        });

    });

    // For each element that has a data-type attribute
    $('div[data-type="content"]').each(function () {

        $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
            var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();


            $('.parallax-content').css('bottom', '+' + ((scrolledY * 1.3)) + 'px');
        });

    });

     $(window).scroll(function(){

      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
          $('.sidebar').addClass('fixed');
      } else {
          $('.sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
      }
  });


 });
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed {position:fixed; top:0;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/06qwtgt6/2/)

Comment: Thats removed the effect of the scrolling from the bottom to the top though... i need to keep that and top it when it gets to the bottom, and those also goes outside of the container as well when you scroll right to the bottom, fixed because you done as fixed though....

Comment: I assumed we should maybe get the container height of when that sidebar sits in, and calculate that way? i dont know.

Comment: you need that sidebar to be fixed when we hit the bottom while scrolling huh?

Comment: As it is currently, it scrolls up and need it to stop at the top of the container "parallax-content" so its always in view if that makes sense and of course for it to go back down when you scroll back the other way :) thanks for your help